# Find.by~ Method of WatiN fails to find Element on a random basis (ElementNotFoundException)

Tags: c#, watin

Find.by(Class/Selector/Url) Method of WatiN fails to find Element on a random basis (ElementNotFoundException).

I have tried to fix it for the past 2 weeks but I don't know the reason.
At first, I thought that the problem ocurred just because Find.Selector is not stable and therefore I looked up al Find.Sector parts to deactivate them but the problem still remains same.

I created C# Windows Form project and then coded the Thread as follows:

```
// Frm.cs 
private void RunBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    workerObject = new Worker();
    workerThread = new Thread(workerObject.DoWork);
    workerThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    workerThread.IsBackground = true;

    workerThread.Start();
}


// Worker.cs
[TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
class Worker
{
    [STAThread]
    public void DoWork()
    {
        while( ! _sholdStop)
        {
            // Find Element & Click
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute Find.ByClass, Find.BySelector and Find.ByUrl in the following HTML, they still fail to find Element on a random basis.

```
<ul class="pagenation ult2">
    <li>
        <a href="http://somedomain.com/post/109301/?param=value&param2=value2">
            Click!
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        ...
    </li>
</ul>


// Try 1 :
// browser.Link(Find.ByUrl("http://somedomain.com/post/109301/?param=value&param2=value2")).Click();

// Try 2 :
// browser.Link(Find.BySelector(".ult2 > li > a")).Click();

// Try 3 :
List ul = browser.List(ByClass("pagenation ult2", true));
ul.ListItems[0].ChildWithTag("a", null).Click();
```

Is WatiN not that stable or is there something I am missing?

Comment: What is your default wait timeout for finding elements?

Comment: AttachToBrowserTimeOut / WaitUntilExistsTimeOut / WaitForCompleteTimeOut is Default(30Sec). I tried set 240 but did not avail

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540886/randomly-throwing-invalidcastexception-during-tests

Comment: Try the following: Run (debug) and wait for the error to pop, manually move the *next statement* arrow one line up, and press F10 twice to see if the code is successful the second time. If it is, it probably means the library is unstable and there's nothing you can do about it. I have come across this situation with both `WatiN` and `EntityFramework` when using MySql as database. The hack I used was to wrap it in a several-attempts-try-catch method (e.g rethrow if fails on 3rd attempt).